# Running into an issue trying to center 4 chart JS charts in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a page with a sidepanel taking up `25%` with `float:left` side of the page, and a div with `float:right` taking up the other `75%`. In the right div, there are 4 ChartJS graphs in a 2 by 2 format. For reasons I can't seem to figure out, I can't get the Charts to either align in the center of the div, or get them to stretch out to use the entire div, and not just the left 70ish %. I've tried different floats, text-align, widths, padding and can't seem to get it right.

```
<div class="dashboards">
    <div id="chartsId" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.dashboards {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code you posted: `<canvas width="200" height="200</canvas>` should be `<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>`

Comment: For clarity, is the `.dashboards` class the float:right that takes up 75% of the page?

Comment: Also, are you using Bootstrap? :)

Comment: Thanks @Frish, yes and yes to your second questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if you're using Bootstrap then I think your issue is in the column count.

Bootstrap uses a 12-column layout, and you're using 10 per row (and I say "per row" because you've got 5*4 = 20 columns which have resolved to two 10x10 rows).

Instead try two `row`s, which will work unless you want a one-row layout on desktop or some such. This will look like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><chart /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-5"><chart /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"><chart /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-5"><chart /></div>
</div>
```

Which is OK, but you'll still have the offset problem. And what you'll need to fix that is... [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)! The issue you're facing is again, 10 columns used in a 12-column layout. Something like this, where x is one chart and y is another:

```
|x|x|x|x|x|y|y|y|y| | |
```

By introducing a 1-column offset, you'll center your columns like so:

```
| |x|x|x|x|x|y|y|y|y| |
```

And all you need to do is add `.offset-sm-1` to your columns, like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5 .offset-sm-1"><chart /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 .offset-sm-1"><chart /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5 .offset-sm-1"><chart /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 .offset-sm-1"><chart /></div>
</div>
```

And you should have nice centered charts.

Comment: Hi @frish, just tried this with no luck. Still seems to be the same for whatever reason

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the 12 layout though, I am quite new to this as you can probably tell and that is at least a pretty good solution to just update it to `col-sm-6`

Comment: Yes, sometimes better to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the design below suit your question? A simple way here is to use floating elements with defined heights and widths.

Below a working snippet and a screenshot mimicking your design (left and panels) as a visual proof.

[image]

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#leftpanel,
#rightpanel {
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* to include the borders in the dimensions */
}

#leftpanel {
  width: 25%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#rightpanel {
  width: 75%;
  background: #f0f0ff;
}

.dashboards {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* to include the borders in the dimensions */
}

.row {
  margin: auto;
  /* Defining width and height to let the "col-sm-5" class to be defined */
  /* relatively to them.                                                 */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* to include the borders in the dimensions */
  border: 5px solid darkgreen;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.col-sm-5 {
  /* use floating positioning */
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* to include the borders in the dimensions */
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="leftpanel">
    Left panel
  </div>
  <div id="rightpanel">
    Right panel
    <div class="dashboards">
      <div id="chartsId" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this seems to center a bit nicer @Amessihel, but there still appears to be an issue with `border: 4px solid darkgreen;` -- For some reason the charts are still not centered completely as the green border extends out about 20% to the right, so the same issue still appears to exist.

Comment: @Neemaximo, here (Firefox 60.2.x), the green border surrounds the four charts symmetrically (up, down, left, right) and the whole thing is well centered. What browser do you use? (Also, borders here are of course only to show the design.)

Comment: I am using Chrome (most up-to-date version). I mentioned the border because that is how I could tell that the issue still persisted as the green border was not symmetrical as it extended out to the right while the chart did not

Comment: @Neemaximo, check out the update (screenshot + left and right panels). Does it work the same way in your browser?